# session created for every different request

Tags: java, jsp, session, tomcat, servlets

I have one jsp which is refreshing after a fix interval and each time I am sending get request to the controller's(servlet) doGet() method. In this doGet method I am not creating any session and simply dispatching request using RequestDispatcher. So flow is like this->

1. Send Request to Controller's doGet()
2. controller receives request and send response back to jsp
3. repeat step 1 and 2 after fix interval

Now issue is I have used <%@ page session="false" %> in my jsp and also I am not creating any session in doGet() method but still I can see session is getting created for each different request from differnt browsers/client. It is not allowing my jsp to be session less. does tomcat is creating session for each request ? or any other issue is with my code? please help

edit:

`doGet()` method code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse      response) throws ServletException, IOException {
request.setAttribute("xyz",xyz);
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/my.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);  
}
```

If I hit URL http://localhost:8080/MyApp/GetDataFromServlet request will go to GetDataFromServlet servlet and it will redirect to my.jsp and in my.jsp I have used interval of 5 seconds so after 5 seconds request will come again to doGet() method inside GetDataFromServlet servlet.

jsp:

```
<body>

Some element to show : <%=request.getAttribute("xyz") %>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
function refresh() {   

        window.location.reload();              
}
}
setTimeout(refresh, 5000);
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: "... *or any other issue is with my code?*" And how can we possibly know if you are not showing us the relevant parts of your code?

Comment: I have pasted code also

Comment: We can't troubleshoot code we can't see. Post your servlet code and JSP code.

Comment: please check I have added code also